# C++: Typedef of template class

Tags: c++, class, systemc

I'm trying to create `typedef` of a vector class I have. I have found similar problems on SO, but they focus on classes that are templates that accept different types of data, while my class is template based on integers.

So, my class is defined like this:

```
namespace sc_dt {
  template <int W> class sc_bv { ... }; //meaning systemc_bit_vector
}
```

And I want to use typedef so I wouldn't have to type in `sc_dt::` every time. However, by using this:

```
typedef sc_dt::sc_bv<int> sc_vector;
```

I get the following error:

> Type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template argument list

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your template parameter is an `int` value, and not a class. You can define `typedef sc_dt::sc_bv<0> sc_vector`, for example.

Comment: Not to doubt the sincerity of your plight, but how much of a hassle is it really to type `sc_dt::sc_bv` compared to  `sc_vector`? It's only 3 character extra.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good point. I would've probably named it `sc_v` in the end, but even that doesn't make it much shorter. Reason 1 is that, when I faced a problem and didn't know how to solve it, it began troubling me, so I wanted to know how to do it. ... if its just for brevity, I could've used `using sc_dt::sc_bv`

Comment: @Rorschach If I were you I would probably refrain from re-naming to already templated class named `sc_vector` in `sc_core` namespace, reference available [here](https://eda-playground.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/systemc-2.3.1/sysc/a00227.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
namespace sc_dt {
  template <int W> class sc_bv { ... } //meaning systemc_bit_vector
}
```

Has a non-type template parameter.  When you instantiate an object of `sc_bv` you need to give it an `int` constant like

```
sc_dt::sc_bv<2> foo;
```

As you can see that is different than

```
typedef sc_dt::sc_bv<int> sc_vector;
```

Where you gave it a type, instead of a value.

If you know what value you want to use for `sc_vector` then you could use

```
typedef sc_dt::sc_bv<the_value_that_you_want_to_use> sc_vector;
```

or if you just want `sc_vector` to be a new name for the class template then you can use an alias template like

```
template<int value>
using sc_vector = sc_dt::sc_bv<value>;
```

which then lets you use `sc_vector` like

```
sc_vector<some_value> foo;
```

Comment: In my understanding, the point of the typedef was just to save typing work, not to refer to a particular template instantiation. In other words, the alias should still be a template.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yeah.  Just added that.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 5):

`typedef`s can't be templated. However, `using`s can be (and this achieves the desired effect):

```
template<int W>
using sc_vector = sc_dt::sc_bv<W>;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you do not want to type namespace `sc_dt::` every time, `using` the namespace or

```
using sc_dt::sc_bv;
```